# Value console logs as true, but claims false in if statement

Tags: javascript, express

So I have this code

```
router.get("/timecard", ensureAuthenticated, async(req, res)=>{
    users = await User.find();
    console.log(req.user.cwlEmployee);
    if(req.user.cwlEmployee !== true){
        req.flash('error_msg', 'You do not have access to that page, sorry.');
        res.render('dashboard', {
            name: req.user.name
        })
    }else{
        res.render('ep/timecard', {
            name: req.user.name,
            users: users
        });
}});
```

the console.log() outputs true, but the if statement right below it is acting as if req.user.cwlEmployee = false.

What could be causing this? I have used this code snippet in many other locations of my code and it works fine elsewhere.

Comment: What is the type of `req.user.cwlEmployee`? `console.log(typeof req.user.cwlEmployee)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `req.user.cwlEmployee` is truthy but not equal to type `boolean` with value `true`.

Comment: You the hero, it wasn't a boolean XD